# How to pair existing Bluetooth earphones without disconnecting from device?

Tags: bluetooth

The same goes for both headphones and BT mice. For instance, when I share the same BT Mice between computers 1,2 and 3, I always need to disconnect it from 1 first before i can connect to another. In Windows, even if com 1 is not on and my mouse was previously paired with 1, it will stay paired and I need to initiate pairing on 2 and 3.

This is super annoying. Is there any easier way to share 1 bt device across computers and android/iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

It entirely depends on the whether or not the Bluetooth device supports multiple clients. You might find that your mouse simply does not have the capability to remember multiple pairing partners.

If that is the case, you will need to continue to pair and unpair the device whenever you switch computers.

If your device does support multiple pairing partners, you can simply turn Bluetooth off on every computer except the one you are currently using. After that, it's up to how your Bluetooth device behaves, either it will automatically connect to the next available client, or require a power cycle to initiate the Bluetooth connection scan.